# Shiny in R: How to properly use reactive, observe and renderUI?

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have a problem with my code. Every time I click a button my plot (built with ggvis) is showing up but vanishes immediately. Since my code is very long, the following code reproduces my problem. I want to reuse the reactive data frame test0 in my render function and I guess this is exactly what causes my problem. But this is essential to me. The three steps (reactive, observe, render) are the same than in my code. I would very much appreciate your help!

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

data(mtcars)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

test0 <- reactive({
  df <- mtcars %>% select(mpg, wt)
  (input$NextCounter + 1)*df
})

observe({
  df <- test0()
  if (!is.null(df)) {
     ggvis(df, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) %>% bind_shiny("plotggvis")
  }
})

output$test1 <- renderUI({
  df <- test0()
  ggvisOutput("plotggvis")
})

})
```

**ui.R**

library(shiny)

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

 sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(

   actionButton("NextCounter", "Next")
  ),

  mainPanel(
   uiOutput("test1")
 )
)
))
```

Comment: `ggvisOutput`  should eb in the UI side

Comment: @ s.brunel Thank you for your comment! So you mean, putting ggvisOutput in UI solves the entire issue? But is this the only solution? Since for layout-reasons it's sometimes important to create the entire output in server...

Comment: you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088248/rendering-ggvis-controls-in-shiny it should help

Comment: this is very helpful - thank you very much! But it's still a pity that there is no solution, which allows to do everything on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

this one working for me

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(

  actionButton("NextCounter", "Next")
),

    mainPanel(
    ggvisOutput("plotggvis")
    )
  )
        ))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data(mtcars)

  test0 <- reactive({
df <- mtcars %>% select(mpg, wt)
(input$NextCounter + 1)*df
  })


  my_graph <- reactive({
    df <- test0()
    ggvis(df, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) 

})

  my_graph %>% bind_shiny("plotggvis") 

  })

})



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a `ggvisOutput` in the UI to solve your problem. Actually the problem in your code is having the `bind_shiny` function inside an observer that will be executed again every time your `test0` data changes. It is expected to bind your ggvis only once, otherwise it will have that behavior of showing up and vanishes immediately. Also, one great feature of ggvis is having a nice transitions when data is changing, so you don't need to create a ggvis object every time your data changes, just make sure that you only bind that ggvis object once in your UI.

Below is a modified version of your code to solve your problem and show the animated transition of data.

```R
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

data(mtcars)

ui <- fluidPage(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("NextCounter", "Next")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("test1")
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {
  test0 <- reactive({
    input$NextCounter
    df <- mtcars %>% select(mpg, wt)
    df[sample(nrow(df),nrow(df)/2), ]
  })
  output$test1 <- renderUI({
    # bind the ggvis only once
    test0 %>% ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) %>% bind_shiny("plotggvis")
    ggvisOutput("plotggvis")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You can also modify some ggvis parameters using input widgets by putting the `ggvis` inside of a reactive expression.